# When would std::common_type be used with a single argument?

Tags: c++, duration, c++-chrono

I noticed that `std::chrono::duration`’s unary + and - operators as implemented in [libcxx](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/chrono) have the return type `typename common_type<duration>::type`. Why is it not simply `duration`, like the other arithmetic operators?

Comment: [p0548r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0548r1.pdf) has some useful references and may shed some light

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a C++17 change. The document [p0548r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0548r1.pdf) tweaks the return types of `operator+` and `operator-` for `duration` to contain:

```
constexpr common_type_t<duration> operator+() const; 
constexpr common_type_t<duration> operator-() const;
```

Obviously `common_type_t` is equivalent to `common_type<duration>::type`. The rationale is essentially to be consistent with the binary `operator+` and `operator-`.